# How to to make LAG() and LEAD() ignore NULLS over multiple rows in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset with data from multiple people and multiple platform. Each person's ranking can change every day or week, but sometimes the data has null values instead of the last known ranking. Furthermore, sometimes the rankings are missing. The data looks like this:

| ID# | Date | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 8/1 | 1 |
| 100 | 8/15 | 1 |
| 100 | 9/10 | 2 |
| 100 | 10/1 | 3 |
| 100 | 10/2 |  |
| 100 | 10/3 |  |
| 100 | 10/4 | 3 |
| 200 | 9/15 |  |
| 200 | 9/16 |  |
| 200 | 9/17 |  |
| 200 | 10/2 |  |
| 200 | 10/6 | 8 |
| 200 | 10/7 | 9 |
| 200 | 10/8 | 9 |

I'd like to fill in the null values with the last known ranking (for ID 100) and the first known ranking (for ID 200).

| ID# | Date | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 8/1 | 1 |
| 100 | 8/15 | 1 |
| 100 | 9/10 | 2 |
| 100 | 10/1 | 3 |
| 100 | 10/2 | 3 |
| 100 | 10/3 | 3 |
| 100 | 10/4 | 3 |
| 200 | 9/15 | 8 |
| 200 | 9/16 | 8 |
| 200 | 9/17 | 8 |
| 200 | 10/2 | 8 |
| 200 | 10/6 | 8 |
| 200 | 10/7 | 9 |
| 200 | 10/8 | 9 |

I'd appreciate any advice on how to do this. I tried the LAG() and LEAD() function, but it carries over the null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs, you can see that `LAG()` and `LEAD` can `IGNORE NULLS`:

```sql
select col_1, col_2, lag(col_2) ignore nulls over (order by col_1) 
from t1
order by col_1;
```

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html

(Please share the queries you've tried next time)